# Why the following ngIf does not work?

Tags: angular

I am just trying the following ngIf based on the status and if the fromDate has value, but it does not seem to work

```
<button *ngIf="fromDate && calendarStatus === 'today' || 'tomorrow' " type="button">
```

Comment: Use this `<button *ngIf="fromDate && calendarStatus === 'today' || calendarStatus ==='tomorrow' " type="button">`

Comment: "does not seem to work" is not a useful problem description. You know much more about it, don't you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your desired logic is being phrased incorrectly.  Assuming you require a calendar status of either today or tomorrow, you could use this:

```
<button ngIf="fromDate && (calendarStatus === 'today' || calendarStatus === 'tomorrow')"
     type="button">
```

The `&&` operator has greater precedence than the `||` operator in JavaScript, hence the need for parentheses, assuming my guess about your logic be correct.

Comment: It is not working when calendarStatus is other than today and tomorrow

Comment: @faceturn What should happen in this case?  Should the button show for calendar status other than today or tomorrow?

Comment: @faceturn : Did u mean calendarStatus not equal to 'today' or 'tomorrow'??

Answer (score 0):

Try below condition :

```
<button *ngIf="fromDate && ['today', 'tomorrow'].indexOf(calendarStatus) !== -1 " type="button">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<button *ngIf="(fromDate && calendarStatus === 'today') || 
               (calendarStatus === 'tomorrow') " 
        type="button">
```